# How to increase the size of first character in a chapter (Drop-Caps)

Tags: paragraphs, lettrine, drop-cap

I would like to know how I can increase the size of the first alphabet of first paragraph of a chapter using (Xe/La/?)tex. Please look at the image shown below.

[image: Image related to question]

1. What is such an effect called? How do I achieve it using Latex?
2. Are there any special fonts to be used for this purpose that contain ornamental/decorative alphabet faces? Or can it be achieved by some manipulation of existing alphabet glyphs?
3. I am not a designer. I know this site is focused on Tex and not typography but I'd appreciate any pointers to popular typeface combinations for this purpose with popular text faces. E.g. If I am using Adobe Garamond Pro as my text face, what would be a suitable type to use for such a first-alphabet-decoration?
4. And finally *(this question may tantamount to heresy here)*: Is there a way to do this in Microsoft Word / OpenOffice?

Comment: The buzzword is *drop caps*. [Here is a link](http://www.littleboxofideas.com/blog/features/the-allure-of-drop-caps-in-typography-practices-and-resources) and [this](http://www.dailydropcap.com/) for lots of resources.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

These are called dropcaps or [lettrine](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lettrine) (from the French). The best package to use is `lettrine` which is available from ctan.

Use as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\begin{document}
    \lettrine{A}{gain find} more words her...
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

They are very difficult to handle typographically, unless the whole page design has been developed with dropcaps incorporated. The modern trend is to use a sans serif font rather than a serified for the dropcap.

Can Microsoft do it? It can, but not recommended to be used for typesetting books.

Comment: Thanks at lot. Can you clarify what you mean by "they are very difficult to handle typographically". Difficult to handle by what? Tex?

Comment: @hashable Difficult to blend with the design. For example in a novel, they might look ok, but not in many other publications. Ask yourself, what function do they serve? Their function is only decorative, so in effect you decorating a page! Technically there is no problem to handle them with (La)TeX. What type of book are you writing?

Comment: You can see some (probably quite good) examples in the Showcase thread: [1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24719/11002) [2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69270/11002) [3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74609/11002) [4](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52675/11002)

Answer (score 5):

1. (Dropped) initial (and some small caps following).  See eg here: http://www.ctan.org/keyword/dropped
2. See eg http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/putting-colors-in-initials/
3. I don't know.
4. Probably yes.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to use the [Linux Libertine and Biolinum fonts](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/libertine), loading them with the command

```
\usepackage{libertine}
```

in the preamble, you can create drop-caps with the commands

```
\LlettrineS[<height in number of lines>]{<letter>} % w/ border
\LlettrineM[<height in number of lines>]{<letter>} % w/ mosaic

\renewcommand*\LlettrineDline{<height in number of lines>} % followed by
\LlettrineD{<letter>} % for display-style letters
```

There are also related commands if you want to use the Biolinum (sans-serif) font. Overall, the manual says that the production of drop caps ("lettrine"s) is still in development. At this time, this approach may be a bit experimental... Give it a chance and see if you like the results...