# create elegant display of digits and symbols

Tags: typography

I want to create a display of the duodecimal digits of `\pi` for printing on a T shirt. I've made some progress with help from SE: [Fonts larger than \Huge?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265/fonts-larger-than-huge), [How to increase the size of first character in a chapter (Drop-Caps)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38108/how-to-increase-the-size-of-first-character-in-a-chapter-drop-caps).

Here's my MWE

```
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,48pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lettrine}

\newcommand{\sirdot}{\smash{\raisebox{.2ex}{$\odot$}}}
\newcommand{\apple}{\smash{$\Delta$}}

\begin{document}

%3:184809493B918664573A6211BB151551A05729290A7809

\noindent
3.184809493\apple 918664573\sirdot 6211\apple\apple 151551\sirdot
05729290\sirdot 7809

\vspace{1in}

\begin{minipage}{4.5in}
\noindent
\lettrine{3.}
1 8 4 8 0 9 4 9 3 \apple{} 9 1 8 6 6 4 5 7 3 \sirdot{}
6 2 1 1 \apple{} \apple{}
1 5 1 5 5 1 \sirdot{}
0 5 7 2 9 2 9 0 \sirdot{} 7 8 0 9 \ldots
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm asking here for answers to questions about the aesthetics.

- Font suggestions?
- Change the interword spacing? (see
  [How to change the interword spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19236/how-to-change-the-interword-spacing))
- Arrange the display in a circle, or running around a circle, perhaps
  with the 3. in the center?
- Make the dropped cap 3. an image, perhaps with a circle in the
  background?

(For information about *why* I want to do this, see [duodecimal page number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59196/duodecimal-page-number).)

**Edit:**

I've accepted @Gonzalo Medina's lovely answer below, with the circular display and font
`\usepackage[fulloldstylenums]{kpfonts}` (and a somewhat smaller central 3.). But ambition knows no bounds.

The `\sirdot` character does not look as if it belongs in the font. Can I have a new character with that essential shape that fits better? Perhaps the `0` with a dot in the center? And, for good measure - the `\Delta` does seem to belong (the thick and thin elements match nicely). But the top of the character ought to look more like the top of the 4, and the horizontal should probably be thick rather than thin. Something like this (hacked with images and paint):

[image: character revisions]

**Edit:**

@Gonzalo Medina answered this new question for `\sirdot`and suggested importing from another font for the `\Delta`m. The one from the default font in my MWE may be better than the one in the accepted answer. How do I grab that? The answer at 
[Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) should do the job.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's one possibility, using `TikZ` and its `decorations.text` library (the digits are used as text for a decoration); I also used the `fulloldstylenums` option for the [`kpfonts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/kpfonts) package:

```
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,48pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[fulloldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\newcommand{\sirdot}{\smash{\raisebox{.2ex}{$\odot$}}}
\newcommand{\apple}{\smash{$\Delta$}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
decoration={text along path,
text={184809493{\apple}918664573{\sirdot}6211{\apple\apple}15%
1551{\sirdot}05729290{\sirdot}7809{\ldots}}}
]
\draw [decorate,rotate=-90] (0,0) circle (7.3cm);
\node at (0,0) {3.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Two variations:

```
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,48pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[fulloldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\newcommand{\sirdot}{\smash{\scalebox{.8}{$\odot$}}}
\newcommand{\apple}{\smash{\scalebox{.8}{$\Delta$}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
decoration={text along path,
text={184809493{\apple}918664573{\sirdot}6211{\apple\apple}15%
1551{\sirdot}05729290{\sirdot}7809{\ldots}}}]
\draw [decorate,rotate=-90] (0,0) circle (7.1cm);
\node at (0,0) {\fontsize{200}{12}\selectfont 3.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
decoration={text along path,
text={184809493{\apple}918664573{\sirdot}6211{\apple\apple}15%
1551{\sirdot}05729290{\sirdot}7809{\ldots}}}]
\draw [decorate,rotate=-90] (0,0) circle (7.1cm);
\node at (0,0) {\fontsize{100}{12}\selectfont$\pi\approx 3.$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Another one (with a little more patience the font size can be better diminished):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[fulloldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\newcommand{\sirdot}{\smash{\scalebox{.8}{$\odot$}}}
\newcommand{\apple}{\smash{\scalebox{.8}{$\Delta$}}}

\newcommand\myfont[1]{\fontsize{#1}{12}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
decoration={text along path,
text={{\myfont{150}1}{\myfont{130}8}{\myfont{140}4}{\myfont{130}8}{\myfont{120}0}{\myfont{110}9}{\myfont{100}%
4}{\myfont{90}9}{\myfont{80}3}{\myfont{70}\apple9}{\myfont{60}18}{\myfont{50}6645}{\myfont{40}73{\sirdot}62}{\myfont{30}11{\apple\apple}15}%
{\myfont{20}1551{\sirdot}}{\myfont{10}05729290}{\sirdot}7809{\ldots}}}]
\draw [decorate,rotate=-90] (0,0) circle (6.8cm);
\node at (0,0) {\fontsize{200}{12}\selectfont 3.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the new requirement made in an edit to the original question, you can use `\ooalign` to superimpose a `\cdot` over an "O" or over a "0" and get the desired symbol; the following code illustrates two possible definitions and shows a comparison with the original symbol:

```
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,48pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[fulloldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\sirdot}{\smash{\scalebox{.8}{$\odot$}}}
\newcommand\sirdoti{%
  \mathord{\ooalign{\hss\raisebox{-0.1ex}{$\cdot$}\hss\cr 0}}}
\newcommand\sirdotii{%
  \mathord{\ooalign{\hss$\cdot$\hss\cr\small O}}}

\begin{document}

$\sirdot\qquad\sirdoti\qquad\sirdotii$

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the other character, perhaps one could impost this symbol from another font?

Comment: nice! Perhaps the 3. should be larger. Raising the circle symbol (necessary for the linear text) seems wrong on the circle. I might need to play with that.

Comment: @EthanBolker you're right. I added two new variations.

Comment: @Gonazalo Medina - nicer still!. See my edit above for further refinement queries.

Comment: Make it look like a slice of pie, and you've got a winner.

Comment: @EthanBolker I updated my answer with two possible replacements for the original `\sirdot` command.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Taking the new `\sirdot` and asking a further question about help importing from another font.

Comment: Nice! At first sight this looked like a Ring inscription.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina  For closure: I used 60 point type,  sirdot `\mathord{\ooalign{\hss\raisebox{-0.1ex}{$\cdot$}\hss\cr 0}}`, original `Delta`,  radius 8.9 cm. The shirts were a great success. Make yourself one.

Comment: @EthanBolker I am glad to hear the shirts were a success :-)