# digits of pi in a spiral

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to draw using Tikz a picture with the digits of pi in a spiral text  like this. Could you help?
[image: digits of pi in a spiral path]

Comment: ...as text there is [a bunch of digits of pi available online](http://www.piday.org/million/)...

Comment: I am **sure** I've seen here a post with an image like this with `\pi` in base 12 (or whatever — about aligning symbols with number). Can't find it...

Comment: Found... http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82867/create-elegant-display-of-digits-and-symbols -- not a spiral though

Comment: I knew this and was able reproduce it for my poster. But one with more cycles is better.